# How to find a value in a cell with vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have to find the value of a cell and in the same way get the number of the row, using VBS. I have tried with solutions that came with VBA but they have not worked for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, sorry about the negative. He won't let me take it off. I'm new around here and I'm not sure how this is going.
   I send you the code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Route=(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName))&"\"   ' Route = folder   



Set objExcel1 = createobject("Excel.application")   'we create Excel object

objExcel1.Visible = True   'we make it visible

Set objWorkbook = objExcel1.Workbooks.open (Route&"Book.xlsx")    'we open it

Set objSheet = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)  'we select the sheet num 1


value="Hello"    ' Hello is an example, is the value that we are going to look for


yy=30  'We assume we have a sheet of 30 rows
xx=40   'and 40 columns

For y1=1 to yy 
     cc=0    'control variable
           For x1=1 to xx

                if  objExcel1.Cells(y1, x1).Value=value then cc=1 :exit for '

            next

     if cc=1 then exit for  'cc=1 we leave the second loop

next

If cc=1 then Msgbox " Found value in Column="&x1 &"  Row="&y1  

if cc=0 then Msgbox "Value not found"



msgbox "End",4096
```